# Setting the output of WMIC commands to variable .bat

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I am trying to add a currently logged in user feature to a .bat support menu i have created.

I am trying to get just the username of the currently logged in user.

I have tried to the following;

The command;

%MID% is a variable set elsewhere in the file.

```
wmic /node:%MID% computersystem get username
```

This returns;

Username
DOMAIN\USER

I am trying to capture the username only.

Tried to do it using tokens and delims but can't seem to get the syntax correct, tried;

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a ('wmic /node:%MID% computersystem get username') do set CUSER=%%a
```

CUSER returns blank.

Any assitance will be very much appreciated.

I understand there are other ways to do this, but i feel accomplishing this task will assist my learning and understanding of WMIC and .bat syntax, I would like to solve this very specifically.

Appreciate ya face in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) method, this is probably how I would retrieve the UserName only:

```batch-file
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2 Delims=\" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" /Node:"%MID%" ComputerSystem Get UserName"') Do Set "CUSER=%%G"
```

Comment: This worked an absolute treat and i could read it and understand why it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about skipping first and last line?

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('wmic /node:"%MID%" computersystem get username') do if not defined CUSER set CUSER=%%a
```

As you are skipping 1 line (`skip=1`) and at second line you are looking if *`%cuser%`* is defined. If it's not, set the content to the result.
At next line, as it will be defined, it will do nothing.

I will recommend you putting the `/node` in quotation marks because if it contains dashes (`-`) it might fail.

Comment: thanks for your reply, im sure this would work but went with the other method, thaks for taking the time to share with me

Answer (score 0):

I only realized now that you wanted `username` only:

```
@for /f "tokens=2delims=\" %%a in ('wmic /node:"%MID%" computersystem get username /value ^| findstr "="') do @set CUSER=%%a
echo %CUSER%
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, im sure this would work but went with the other method, thaks for taking the time to share with me